Inclusion and Exclusion of US states
Is the first sentence fragment written with better English usage than the second? Or, are both of the sentence fragments acceptable?

... in all the US states, excluding Alaska.

... in 49 of the US states, excluding Alaska.



#1 is better than #2, because 49-1=48. But in both, you can't have United States states.

The expression "US states" is common and OK: National Geographic, US Department of the Interior, Statista.

@YosefBaskin: That's a bit pedantic. With or without periods, the abbreviation US has become "lexicalized" (same as your credit card PIN Number, where PIN=Personal Identification Number). See this usage chart for ...in all states except ???, showing that OP's Alaska is more likely to be excluded / excepted than Hawaii, which was my first guess.

@SBerman: I'm pretty certain far more native Anglophones would use except rather than excluding in your context. Apart from anything else, if you follow the usage chart link in my previous comment, and change except to excluding, there's no data to show in the chart.

@YosefBaskin Why can't you have United States states? "United States" is the name of the country, and "states" after it means states within that country. It's analogous to "Germany states" or "Canada provinces". It's just a coincidence that the name of the country happens to end with the same word, making it seem redundant like PIN number and ATM machine.

@Barmar "PIN number and ATM machine," my favorites.

Despite the title, nothing in this question is really specific to the US. What we have here is just a garden-variety possibility of the same phrase sometimes being used restrictively and sometimes not.

In my opinion, #1 is preferable, although I don't think the comma is needed.
#2 can be reworded by putting the exclusion in a parenthetical, to indicate that it's simply clarifying which 49 states are included.

... in 49 of the US states -- Alaska is excluded.

or

... in 49 of the US states (Alaska excluded).

